# Як передати зловісний сміх письмово?

Tags: правопис

Як в українській мові передаються звуки сміху?

Відомі мені приклади включають лише `ги-ги-ги` у варіаціях, і їх контекст вживання є загалом нейтральним:

- [`ги-ги-и`](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13131802----) у Винничука;
- [`ги-ги-ги`](http://ukrslovo.net/family-circle/zdorovya/20942.html) загалом;

Чи передається якось відмінно зловісний/зловтішний сміх? Наприклад, в коміксах, або інших літературних творах, у виконанні негативних персонажів, а чи й у в повсякденному мовленні (блоги, соцмережі).

Російською часто зустрічала варіант `муа-ха-ха-ха`.

Comment: Чи не здається вам, що це занадто суб’єктивне? Це таке саме, коли спитати, як у коміксах українською передається звук сірника, що падає на мармурову підлогу, чи зойк сніжинок, що лягали на гілках, аби поринути у свій безмежний сон. ;)

Comment: @YellowSky, На інших сайтах подібні запитання пробігають. Не можу швидко наґуґлили, але [here, for one](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/119108/27). Або [ось, marginally related](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/107781/27). Хоча ви маєте рацію, що такі запитання запрошують до суб'єктивних відповідей. Зараз post notice поставлю.

Comment: @YellowSky, можливо, я не дуже добре пояснила контексти вживання цього вигуку(?), але деякими не літературними прикладами із зловтішним `муа-ха-ха-ха` російською є [раз](https://goo.gl/Vxqxw1), [два](https://goo.gl/L8iDdA), [три](https://es-la.facebook.com/babchenkoa/posts/742783215821914). Зараз спробую переформулювати питання.

Comment: Під «суб’ективним» я мав на увазі, що хіба ж усі зловтішно сміються однаковими літерами? Один може так сміятися, а другий геть инакше. Коли йдеться про комікси, то там дійсно можуть вживатися стандартні звуконаслідувальні кліше, тільки от це стосується скоріш не мови, а коміксної культури, яка, скажімо, в Японії розвинена настільки, що там цих кліше сотні, є навіть для різних емоцій, запахів, різних видів болю, температури повітря, тощо. У нас коміксна культура відсутня. Тому тут 2 шляхи: або запозичуємо чужу, або _створюємо_ свою, вже готових відповідей на це питання ви не знайдете.

Comment: @YellowSky, тепер розумію ваше зауваження, маєте рацію. А щодо створення своєї комікс-культури, то [отут](http://www.ugar.com.ua/komiksy/komiks-volyathe-will/) лупають сю скалу :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Гучний** (іноді *зловтішний*) сміх — «**бу-га-га**», «**бга-га-га**»:

- Григір Тютюнник «[Обмарило](http://www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=560)»:

  > — Га-га-га,— засміявся Антін. — Точно, набік.
  >
  > — Кривоматній! — підсипала Палажка, **теж** закипаючи **зловтішним** сміхом.
  >
  > — **Бга-га-га**... Кривоматній!.. — забухикав Антін.
  >
  > — Хі-хі-хі-і... — зашилася Палажка, наливаючись від напруги дівочим рум'янком. — Розтапша нещасний...
- Коментарі в Інтернеті:

  - > Після ботокса став похожий на жирного японця, бга-га-га-га, єврей в вишиванці з мордою японця, бга-га-га-га.
  - > А безвізовий? Бга-га-га-га-га-а-га-га-га-га-га-на, а чому цього року не повернула? Бга-га-га-га, Боже мені встидно що я народився в цій недодержаві, де людей мають за довбнів, хоча і довбнів не мало, бо було б мало, то не знущалися б з нас так. Як говориться: чого бідні — бо дурні, а чого дурні — бо бідні. Де б так німець дав себе згнидити і зачмирити загнавши нище плінтуса.
- Всеволод Нестайко «П'ятірка з хвостиком: дилогія в оповіданнях про два класи», частина перша «Одиниця „з обманом“: повість в оповіданнях пол 4-Б клас» (в збірках [«Тореадори з Васюківки: вибрані повісті»](//books.google.com/books?id=FU_qAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F%22) (1980), [«П'ятірка з хвостиком: вибрані твори в двох томах: том другий»](http://shron.chtyvo.org.ua/Nestaiko/Vybrani_tvory_Tom_2_Piatirka_z_khvostykom.pdf) (1990, Київ, «Веселка»), [«Супер „Б“ з „фрикадельками“»](//books.google.com/books?id=eaqBAQAAQBAJ&q=%22%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F%22) і [«Пригода в кукурудзі»](//books.google.com/books?id=78cy9qx3PdQC&q=%22%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F%22)):

  > А сніговик усміхався, і всім здавалося, ніби він аж підморгує — неодмінно, мовляв, простою до самісінької весни!
  >
  > І раптом... раптом сталося несподіване.
  >
  > З-за паркану вилетіла каменюка і вдарила сніговика по голові, аж усіх запорошило снігом. Гуркочучи поко­тилося порожнє відро-капелюх. Весела усмішка снігови­ка розсипалася на тисячі сріблястих сніжинок.
  >
  > Якусь мить сніговик стояв без голови. Та нараз друга каменюка бухнула йому в груди, сніговик похитнувся, мітла випала з його руки, він упав і розсипався...
  >
  > — Бу-га-га! — з-за паркану показалась хлоп’яча го­лова в кошлатій шапці-вушанці.
- Брати Капранови «Розмір має значення» (2006):

  > — Бу-га-га! — розвеселилася охорона, що, певно, чекала на цю виставу.